# Restore MySQL databases from data files (Windows to Unix)

Tags: mysql, database

Recently my Windows machine had a problem and I was only able to log in to safe mode. As such, I could not get Apache or MySQL to run. The only thing I was able to do was to take a backup of the MySQL data directory.

After reinstalling Windows on the machine, I wanted to try an alternative (better) development environment, and I stumbled across Vagrant. I managed to get this set up using VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu on to it.

In the backup of the data directory, I have:

1. Individual folders that represent each database
2. The following files: `auto.cnf`, `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1`

The databases I have contain a combination of `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` databases.

Now what I want to do is restore the databases into MySQL. I am not too familiar with Unix commands, so I used FileZilla to SSH in to the VM. I then found the location of the data directory in Ubuntu, which is `/var/lib/mysql`.

Firstly I had to change the permissions of this directory so that I could transfer the files to it.

I stopped the mysql service and then copied across one of the folders. I then restarted mysql. After doing this I opened up phpmyadmin. The database I copied over was listed, however when I clicked on to it only one table was showing (should be 4). Clicking on this table to browse the data gave me an error `#1033 - incorrect information in file 'product.frm'`.

Also I noticed the other 3 tables were listed in the left hand column, but clicking on these gave me an error `#1146 - Table 'category' doesn't exist`.

I also tried copying across the `ib` files, but after doing this the mysql service would not start.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? Is it anything to do with the fact the files originated from Windows? Or am I doing the process incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the MySQL data directory is portable across different operating systems (namely, MySQL doesn't handle changes in file-system case-sensitivity well at all, among other issues). Your best option is to restore the data directory (a "physical" dump) in Windows, and use `mysqldump` to get a set of SQL commands (a "logical" dump). You can then import this file using PHPMyAdmin's import feature, or by using a shell command.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice and did just that.

I installed MySQL server on my Windows Machine, then copied across my data directory backup to the new data directory, then used MySQL Workbench to generate a SQL backup of all the databases.

Then imported this backup file into the VM using MySQL Workbench again.

This whole process was not easy, I did have a few hiccups along the way but got it sorted in the end :)